# Where did the free space for my deleted ExFAT partition go?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, exfat

I had these partitions on an external hard drive:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Android                 63.9 GB    disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS RiptideHUP              968.0 GB   disk2s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data RiptideF                967.8 GB   disk2s4
```

My aim was to delete disk2s2 and then resize disk2s3 to occupy the leftover space by deleting disk2s2. 
I deleted disk2s2 using this command:

```
diskutil  erasevolume  "Free Space"  ""  /dev/disk2s2
```

Now, to resize the volume, I used:

```
diskutil  resizevolume  /dev/disk2s3  R
```

However, I got this error:

```
Started partitioning on disk2s3 RiptideHUP Error: -69743: The new size
must be different than the existing size
```

Can someone help me and tell me where I went wrong?

**NOTE:** Using `diskutil list` now shows:

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS RiptideHUP              968.0 GB   disk2s3
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data RiptideF                967.8 GB   disk2s4
```

Answer (score 0):

The command `diskutil  resizevolume  /dev/disk2s3  R` requires the free space to reside after `disk2s3`. The command `diskutil  erasevolume  "Free Space"  ""  /dev/disk2s2` created free space before `disk2s3`. There is no or very little free space between `disk2s3` and `disk2s4`. This is why you received the error message.

Comment: Thanks! So is there a way I can still utilise this Free Space?

Comment: How much space is `RiptideHUP` using?

Comment: `disk2s3 (RiptideHUP)` uses 968 GB. I'm supposed to have approx. 64 GB free space after deleting `disk2s2 (Android)`